# How to Solve this "missing ) argument after list"?

Tags: javascript

This looks like a trivial question, but I am not sure how to deal with it. I have a `DIV` tag generated from javascript that goes like this:

```
$('#results')
 .append('<DIV id='
 + A.pid
 + ' onmouseover=function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseover');};><H3>'
 + A.name
 + '</H3></DIV>');
```

Firebug is giving me an error "**missing ) argument after list**" as it does not recognise the `)` immediately after `'mouseover'`. How do I resolve this?

**UPDATE:**

I understand this is about escaping quote, just that doing `\'mouseover\'` produces a syntax error upon mouseover of the `DIV` and doing `"mouseover"` produces a blank document.

The syntax error reads: *function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker,*

Comment: I have already flagged this question for removal. Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625248/how-to-do-a-proper-escape-of-this-function) instead.

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape **quote** if it's inside another **quote**:

- `var x = "I don't like you!";`
- `var y = 'I don\'t like you!';`
- `var z = 'echo "this text?";';`

To implement it on your case, it would be like this:

```
'<DIV id='
 + A.pid
 + ' onmouseover=function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker, \'mouseover\');};><H3>'
 + A.name
 + '</H3></DIV>'
```

Comment: @Ben: Try it again and it should work. If not, try it again and then post the error message you get.

Answer (score 1):

You issue is in the use of the `'` character to delimit both the function and the arguments in your call.

Either switch one set of `'` out for `"` or use `\'` around the values of the argument

```
$('#results')
 .append('<DIV id='
 + A.pid
 + ' onmouseover=function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "mouseover");};><H3>'
 + A.name
 + '</H3></DIV>');

//OR

$('#results')
 .append('<DIV id='
 + A.pid
 + ' onmouseover=function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker, \'mouseover\');};><H3>'
 + A.name
 + '</H3></DIV>');
```

Comment: The first one generated a syntax error. The second one produces a blank html document. :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to put " around the values of your html attributes. Otherwise the browser thinks the attribute ends at the next whitespace and that is exactly right after the `(marker,` part.

```
$('#results')
 .append('<DIV id="'
 + A.pid + '"'
 + ' onmouseover="function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker, \'mouseover\');};"><H3>'
 + A.name
 + '</H3></DIV>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate the following string

```
'<DIV id=' + 
A.pid  + 
' onmouseover=\"google.maps.event.trigger(marker, \'mouseover\');\"> <H3>' + 
A.name + '</H3></DIV>'
```

Comment: I have already flagged this question for removal, please refer to my comment below the question. Thanks for your participation :)

Answer (score 0):

Several things

1. Stop putting HTML in all caps.  This is the 21st century not the 20th century.
2. You don't need an anonymous function for the `onmouseover` event.
3. Wrap attribute values in either single or double quotes (I use double below).
4. Read about JavaScript strings and quotes.  Here is a [tutorial](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html).

Try this

```
    $('#results').append('<div id="' +
    A.pid +
    '" onmouseover="google.maps.event.trigger(marker, \'mouseover\');"><h3>' +
    A.name +
    '</h3></div>');
```

Comment: @ DwB, my apologies if you didn't see my comment added 6 hrs ago under the question. I got my answer in another question I posted. Refer to the link on the right panel. The reason why I use caps for HTML elements is for better presentation and to differentiate between PHP and HTML on the same page. I don't understand your 2nd point. For 3rd point, I am using double quotes for PHP and it need to be escaped as well. Thanks for the tutorial, I will read it up. :)