# How to do a Proper Escape of this Function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `DIV` tag generated from jQuery that goes like this:

```
$('#results')
 .append('<DIV id='
 + A.pid
 + ' onmouseover=function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseover');};><H3>'
 + A.name
 + '</H3></DIV>');
```

Firebug is giving me an error "**missing ) argument after list**" as it does not recognise the `)` immediately after `'mouseover'`.

Doing a `\'mouseover\'` produces a syntax error upon mouseover of the `DIV`. The syntax error reads: **function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker,**
and a look at the generated DIV shows:

```
<div id="1" 'mouseover');};="" onmouseover="function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker,">
```

Doing a `"mouseover"` produces a **blank** document.

How do I do a proper escape for this function?

**UPDATE:**

This should work:

```
$('#results')
 .append('<DIV id='
 + A.pid
 + ' onmouseover=\"function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker, \'mouseover\');};\"><H3>'
 + A.name
 + '</H3></DIV>');
```

I need to put escaped double quotes for the function and escaped single quotes for the argument.

Comment: Duplicate of your own question: [How to Solve this "missing ) argument after list"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625059/how-to-solve-this-missing-argument-after-list)

Comment: Yes, the previous question wasn't asked or answered properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put " around the values of your html attributes. Otherwise the browser thinks the attribute ends at the next whitespace and that is exactly right after the `(marker,` part.

```
$('#results')
 .append('<DIV id="'
 + A.pid + '"'
 + ' onmouseover="function(){google.maps.event.trigger(marker, \'mouseover\');};"><H3>'
 + A.name
 + '</H3></DIV>');
```

Comment: The `"` would generate a blank document. But I get what you mean, thanks.

Comment: @Ben Yeah this was a bit ambiguous, I clarified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are putting data in JS in HTML in JS in HTML. Every level of encapsulation there requires a string escape, otherwise out-of-band characters will cause errors and possibly security holes. The human brain is not good at keeping track of multiple nested levels of string encapsulation.

So use jQuery's element creation shortcuts to set attributes on the new div, and the event handling features to add the listener to it, instead of messing around with ugly and unsafe HTML string hacking:

```
var div= $('<div>', {id: A.pid}).append($('<h3>', {text: A.name}));
div.mouseover(function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'mouseover');
});
$('#results').append(div);
```

Comment: The only proper answer. Inline JS is a mess, especially when created by JS.

Comment: I understand what you mean. In fact, I actually began with this approach, but encountered a problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621016/showing-google-maps-marker-infoname-on-mouseover-of-a-dynamically-generated-div). That is why I want to try another approach to see if it works.

Comment: @Ben: answered there. I think you originally had the common Closure Loop Problem, but then broke the code in worse ways by splitting the `process` function without keeping track of `marker`. Putting code in inline event handler attributes wouldn't work because they don't have access to the local `marker` variable you want to reference. Event handlers in HTML attributes don't get to see anything but global variables (and properties of ancestor elements, but that's a horrible confusing feature you never want).